Geometry nodes - Pack UV Mesh quads sliced by Grid into first UDIM (0..1)

I want to place all of slices by grid quads of my mesh with some topology into first UDIM.
I've found solution, but I think it can be improved.
I've used a Scale elements node to avoid errors with Sample Nearest Surface Node, because last one can't calculate/interpolate UV attr correctly due to back-to-back grids (by array node group)
Basically, I want to avoid Split Node, Scale Elements Node, Merge by distance Node
Or another solution...



You're 2D-arraying a default "Grid" and then sample UVs from it, however when you're sampling at a position equal to an edge/corner of the source "Grid" array, there's 2/4 competing faces to sample the attribute from. This is why you're scaling your faces down a little.
However the "Sample Nearest Surface" has a socket "Sample Position" that allows you to override the sampling position. Instead of scaling the face, scale the position by moving it towards the face center:

Inset Coords group:

